# Missing graphics when disassembling and re-assembling .net program

Tags: .net-3.5, ilasm, ildasm

I have a piece of software. When I disassemble the PE file

```
ildasm foo.exe /output=foo.il
```

I get a bunch of files, like `foo.MainForm` and `foo.bar.dll`. When I then try to re-assemble the file

```
ilasm foo.il
```

I get a working foo.exe back again, but some of the small graphics are missing in the new file (it's also ~200kb smaller). Some other graphics are working, so it looks like I'm missing something in the disassemble or re-assemble. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decompile you will see a bunch of .res files extracted.

You need to include them again when recompiling with ilasm.

Comment: Hmm that wasn't that difficult.. I though I completely read all the ilasm/ildasm help, thanks.